# upgrade magento latest version from 1.1.3 through admin dashboard

Tags: magento

I have  a magento site with version 1.1.3. I want to upgrade this to version 1.4.1.0 from mu admin dashboard. Could you please tell me the steps to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

wow, that's a big jump. I would recommend that you use a multi-step approach using the PEAR installer from the command line.  Using the Admin Dashboard for such a big upgrade is very likely to fail.  I'd also recommend that you break the upgrade into (at least) two steps, 1.1.3 to 1.3.2.4 and then 1.3.2.4 to 1.4.1.0.

You can get a listing of available upgrades from PEAR like this:`./pear list-upgrades`

Here's a wiki [page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento) to guide you.

Make sure you take lots and lots of backups...

Good luck!
JD